# own ssd tensorflow model run on android without throwing error,but can't detect anything.Note the network seems right

Tags: android, tensorflow, detect

**question:**
i run tensorflow SSD model on android. The android studio didn't throw error. But i can't detect anything.I test my pb file, it's seems right. I don't know why. Anyone who can help me? Thanks!!

**code:**
because the model is based on tensorflow demo. so i just paste own code.

public List recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    final SplitTimer timer = new SplitTimer("recognizeImage");

```
// Log this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage");

Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap");
// Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
// on the provided parameters.
bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
  floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = ((intValues[i] >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
  floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = ((intValues[i] >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
  floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (intValues[i] & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
}
Trace.endSection(); // preprocessBitmap

// Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
Trace.beginSection("fillNodeFloat");
inferenceInterface.fillNodeFloat(
        inputName, new int[] {1, inputSize, inputSize, 3}, floatValues);
Trace.endSection();

timer.endSplit("ready for inference");

// Run the inference call.
Trace.beginSection("runInference");
final int resultCode = inferenceInterface.runInference(outputNames);
if (resultCode != 0) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Bad result code from inference: " + resultCode);
}
Trace.endSection();

timer.endSplit("ran inference");

// Copy the output Tensor back into the output array.
Trace.beginSection("readNodeFloat");
//推理得到的结果

final float[] outputs=new float[feat_shapes[0][0] * feat_shapes[0][1] * (anchor_sizes[0].length+anchor_ratios[0].length) * 4+
                                      feat_shapes[1][0] * feat_shapes[1][1] * (anchor_sizes[1].length+anchor_ratios[1].length) * 4+
                                      feat_shapes[2][0] * feat_shapes[2][1] * (anchor_sizes[2].length+anchor_ratios[2].length) * 4+
                                      feat_shapes[3][0] * feat_shapes[3][1] * (anchor_sizes[3].length+anchor_ratios[3].length) * 4+
                                      feat_shapes[4][0] * feat_shapes[4][1] * (anchor_sizes[4].length+anchor_ratios[4].length) * 4+
                                      feat_shapes[5][0] * feat_shapes[5][1] * (anchor_sizes[5].length+anchor_ratios[5].length) * 4+
                                      feat_shapes[0][0] * feat_shapes[0][1] * (anchor_sizes[0].length+anchor_ratios[0].length) * NUM_CLASSES+
                                      feat_shapes[1][0] * feat_shapes[1][1] * (anchor_sizes[1].length+anchor_ratios[1].length) * NUM_CLASSES+
                                      feat_shapes[2][0] * feat_shapes[2][1] * (anchor_sizes[2].length+anchor_ratios[2].length) * NUM_CLASSES+
                                      feat_shapes[3][0] * feat_shapes[3][1] * (anchor_sizes[3].length+anchor_ratios[3].length) * NUM_CLASSES+
                                      feat_shapes[4][0] * feat_shapes[4][1] * (anchor_sizes[4].length+anchor_ratios[4].length) * NUM_CLASSES+
                                      feat_shapes[5][0] * feat_shapes[5][1] * (anchor_sizes[5].length+anchor_ratios[5].length) * NUM_CLASSES];

inferenceInterface.readNodeFloat(outputNames[0], outputs);
LOGGER.i("recognizeImage: "+outputs);
Trace.endSection();

// Find the best detections.
final PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
        new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
                1,
                new Comparator<Recognition>() {
                  @Override
                  public int compare(final Recognition lhs, final Recognition rhs) {
                    // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                    return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
                  }
                });

int num=0,offest=0;
float cx,cy,cw,ch,xpos,ypos,h,w;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
  for(int y=0;y<feat_shapes[i][0];y++)
  {
    for(int x=0;x<feat_shapes[i][1];x++)
    {
      ypos=(y+anchor_offset)*anchor_steps[i]/img_shape[0];
      xpos=(x+anchor_offset)*anchor_steps[i]/img_shape[1];
      //预测框
      for(int l=0;l<(anchor_ratios[i].length+2);l++)
      {
        if(l==0)
        {
          h=anchor_sizes[i][0]/img_shape[0];
          w=anchor_sizes[i][0]/img_shape[1];
        }
        else if(l==1)
        {
          h=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(anchor_sizes[i][0]*anchor_sizes[i][1])/img_shape[0]));
          w=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(anchor_sizes[i][0]*anchor_sizes[i][1])/img_shape[1]));
        }
        else
        {
          h=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(anchor_sizes[i][0]/img_shape[0]/Math.sqrt(anchor_ratios[i][l-2])));
          w=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(anchor_sizes[i][0]/img_shape[1]/Math.sqrt(anchor_ratios[i][l-2])));
        }
        //解码
        cx=outputs[offest]*w*prior_scaling[0]+xpos;
        offest++;
        cy=outputs[offest]*h*prior_scaling[1]+ypos;
        offest++;
        cw=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(w*Math.exp(outputs[offest]*prior_scaling[2])));
        offest++;
        ch=Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(h*Math.exp(outputs[offest]*prior_scaling[3])));
        offest++;
        final RectF rect =
                new RectF(
                        Math.max(0, cx - cw / 2),
                        Math.max(0, cy - ch / 2),
                        Math.min(1, cx + cw / 2),
                        Math.min(1, cy + ch / 2));
        //挑选大于select_threshold的框
        offest++;
        for(int m=1;m<NUM_CLASSES;m++)
        {
          if(outputs[offest]>select_threshold)
          {
            LOGGER.i(
                    "%s (%d) %f %s", LABELS[m], m, outputs[offest], rect);
            pq.add(new Recognition("" + num, LABELS[m], outputs[offest], rect));
            num++;
          }
          offest++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
timer.endSplit("decoded results");

final ArrayList<Recognition> sort = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(pq.size(), top_k); ++i) {
  sort.add(pq.poll());
}
timer.endSplit("sorted results");

final ArrayList<Recognition> nms = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
float []keep_bboxes=new float[sort.size()];
for(int i=0;i<sort.size();i++)
{
  keep_bboxes[i]=1;
}
float overlap;
for(int i=0;i<sort.size();i++)
{
  if(keep_bboxes[i]==1)
  {
    for(int j=i+1;j<sort.size();j++)
    {
      overlap=bboxes_jaccard(sort.get(i).getLocation(),sort.get(j).getLocation());
      if(overlap<nms_threshold||sort.get(i).getTitle()!=sort.get(j).getTitle())
      {
        nms.add(sort.get(i));
      }
      else
        keep_bboxes[j]=0;
    }
  }
}
timer.endSplit("nms results");

final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(nms.size(), MAX_RESULTS); ++i) {
  recognitions.add(nms.get(i));
}
Trace.endSection(); // "recognizeImage"

timer.endSplit("processed results");

return recognitions;
```

}

Comment: How did you called  recognizeImage method in your activity? I guess you need to check if you fed bitmap right.

Comment: I test it by detecting image from photo album on android. It succeed! And I found the one without detecting had a layout fidelity warning:The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate-Canvas.drawPaint is not supported. Could it be that question?

Comment: it's still unclear but according to the error message, it seems that you have a problem in the creating bitmap and fed it to inference method when drawing  ?...check before you pass the bitmap to recognizeImage method if the object contains actual bitmap. Maybe posting codes the part before you call the recognizeImage would be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: ok，I will try it according to your advice. Thanks!!